# How to force camera to be in portrait mode using cordova / ionic app?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am working on hybrid app, I am invoking camera from my app I want this camera to be in portrait mode only. I tried doing it by changing config file as:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
```

But as camera open it starts rotation. How do I prevent it?

Comment: There is no way to force the camera orientation.

Comment: you can send a feature request on issues.cordova.io

Comment: You can use `correctOrientation` property in Camera Options.

Answer (score 1):

Exists a plugin to force orientation

https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

Just force portrait before entering camera mode, and disable it after exit.

```
// set to either landscape
screen.lockOrientation('landscape');

// allow user rotate
screen.unlockOrientation();
```

I dont know if this is going to work, because camera is native, but if you embed the camera in your app, works for sure.

Please post your results ;)

Comment: This plugin is setting orientation before app invokes camera. When camera shows there is no control of it. Camera still rotates....